# Imputing categorical data with python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

Is there a way to impute missing value with the mean of a categorical type that this value belongs to. For example if I have 50 unique products which creates 1000 samples where one of the features is weight. Can I impute weight for a product "a" with the mean value of weights of products "a" and product "c" with the mean value of weights  of products "c"?

Comment: Yes, that's a sensible thing to do. You could also use the median which is more robust in the face of outliers.

Comment: If your data have a very large spread, you might consider using the median. The modal class could also be valid depending on the circumstances. You could also justify randomly sampling from "a" and inserting the value at each value requiring imputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using pandas, you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "category": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
    "weight": [1.0, 1.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
})
print df

df["weight"].fillna(df.groupby("category")["weight"].transform("median"), inplace=True)
print df
```

Original dataframe:

```
  category  weight
0        a     1.0
1        a     1.0
2        a     NaN
3        a     2.0
4        b     NaN
5        b     3.0
6        b     3.0
7        b     3.0
```

Result:

```
  category  weight
0        a     1.0
1        a     1.0
2        a     1.0
3        a     2.0
4        b     3.0
5        b     3.0
6        b     3.0
7        b     3.0
```